# How to download image from linkedin by using python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api, urllib

I'm trying to download the companies logoby using urllib in python. But the the src of every image is a link which is not ending on .jpg or .jpeg or any other image file format like: `https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQFV8hEDyrhygA/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1584576000&v=beta&t=rCeGYSP-rfRqEnSRiZszB3F1Bcks7kyXTYoiGrqUPTg`.
I'm using the below code for that:

```
imageSrc = companySoup.find('img', {'class': 'org-top-card-primary-content__logo Elevation-0dp lazy-image loaded ember-view'})
        imageSrcUrl = imageSrc['src'].strip()
        print(imageSrcUrl)
        urllib.urlretrieve(imageSrcUrl, os.path.basename(imageSrcUrl))
```

Please help me that how can I download it in python.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in pygame. But you can modify it to handle the image with whatever you need (e.g. PIL?)

```
import requests
import io
import pygame
import traceback

def loadURLImage(url, headers='', timeout=10):

    image = None

    try:
        with requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout) as pic:
            image_str = pic.content
            image_file = io.BytesIO(image_str)
            # Use .convert_alpha() if you find troubles with transparency
            image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
    except:
        print("Error getting image from URL", url)
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    return image
```

now you can save it to disk (as BMP, TGA, PNG, or JPEG), using:

```
file_name = "test.jpeg"    
pygame.image.save(image, file_name)
```

Comment: Very happy to hear that! Please mark it as the answer so others may find the solution as well!